# iterate through rows, check for an update and then update row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (let's say Table A, on the database), which has been updated over time. And I have another table (Table B, created from an external source) which has also been updated, but via different sources.

Each table has an `ID, Name, RecordDetails, LastUpdatedDate`.

How would I do the following?

- Iterate through Table B, and determine if Table A has the same ID.

  - If it does, compare the LastUpdatedDate field.

    - If B has a more recent LastUpdatedDate, update the record with all of the information for that record from B.
    - Else, do nothing.
- If Table A does not have the same ID, add that record from B into Table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop thinking about looping or iterating. SQL Server (and all RDBMS actually) are optimized to work on sets. Don't think about what you want to do to each individual row; think about what you want to do to a ***set*** of rows.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE A
  SET col1 = B.col1,
      col2 = B.col2, 
      etc.
 FROM dbo.TableA AS A
 INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS B
 ON A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE A.LastUpdatedDate <= B.LastUpdatedDate;

INSERT dbo.TableA(ID, col1, col2, etc.)
 SELECT ID, col1, col2, etc.
  FROM dbo.TableB AS B
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA
      WHERE ID = B.ID
  );

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Others might suggest `MERGE` for this, but [I highly recommend against it](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), and so do [several of my colleagues](https://sqlblog.org/merge).